# Debugging Storm Crawler

Tags: debugging, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

How do you debugging Storm-Crawl?

I mean you wrote something module and you want to check it. You can write unit-test, but you want to check it on system (may be local system), how do you do it?

I think Julien will correctly answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions for that on the project [WIKI](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Debug-with-Eclipse)